# How can I select all columns from a subquery that only contains some?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following query:

```
SELECT id, MAX(`grab_time`) AS `grab_time` FROM events WHERE ended = false GROUP BY id
```

This returns all the records that have the greatest `grab_time` as compared to other records that have the same `id`.

The table `events` has four columns though, and I want them all.  I've been advised to put the above query in to a subquery, in order to get the missing columns (it only shows 2), but I don't know how to do that?

How can I tell sql to basically "SELECT everything WHERE the rows are from the rows in ()"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the IN as

```
select * from events 
where (id,grab_time) in
(SELECT id, MAX(`grab_time`) AS `grab_time` FROM events WHERE ended = false GROUP BY id)
```

You can also use the `MAX` windows function as follows:

```
select * from 
(
select t.*, max(grab_time) over (partition by id) as mx
from your_table where ended = false
)
where grab_time = mx
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a correlated subquery:

```
select e.*
from events e
where not e.ended and
      e.grab_time = (select max(e2.grab_time) from events e2 where e2.id = e.id and not e2.ended);
```

You want an index on `events(id, ended, grab_time)` for this query.

Or use `row_number()`:

```
select e.*
from (select e.*, row_number() over (partition by id order by grab_time desc) as seqnum
      from events e
      where not ended
     ) e
where seqnum = 1;
```

Comment: Just fyi, I couldn't get the bottom method to run without sql errors, and the top one would appear to be running in n^2 time (just on feel, haven't done tests).  As the table grows, it slows down massively.  Tejash's first method is working.

Comment: @DuncanMarshall . . .The first is not O(n^2) if you have an appropriate index.  The second should work, unless you have an old version of MySQL.

Answer (score 1):

One approach can be using temporary tables:

```
   with max_time as
   (
     select id,MAX(grab_time) as grab_time FROM events where ended='false' GROUP BY 
     id
   )
   select * from events e,max_time mt where e.id=mt.id and e.grab_time=mt.grab_time;
```